# Communicate through JSch SSH tunnel with remote process/server

Tags: java, scala, ssh, jsch, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to do programmatically in `JSch` what works fine in Bash.  I set up an SSH tunnel and then communicate through the tunnel.  I'm supposed to send an authentication string every 10 seconds or so, and in return I will get from the remote host a steady stream of lines.  In `JSch` I've established the connection to the remote host Ok, but when I try to set up a channel with the `direct-tcpip` option, reading and writing the channel's `getInputStream` and `getOutputStream`, it throws an exception `failed to initialize the channel`.  After reading what people wrote in other SO answers regarding `JSch`, I did `channel.connect()` before I tried to write to the outputStream.  This is what works in Bash:

In one shell:

```
ssh -l username -L LOCALPORT:127.0.0.1:REMOTEPORT REMOTEHOST
```

In another shell:

```
ID='{ "id": 1234, "auth": "abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" }'
while true; do echo $ID; sleep 10; done | nc localhost LOCALPORT
```

**Attempted/failing bugfix code commenter requested I show:**

When I try **session.setPortForwardingL** and open a Socket to `localhost:tunnelLocalPort`, the session says it is connected and the socket says it is connected but before I can even use the socket, the `DirectTCPIP thread remoteIp` throws `JSchException("channel is not opened") // SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE` at the bottom of `sendChannelOpen()` in `Channel.java`.

```
JSch.setConfig("server_host_key", JSch.getConfig("server_host_key") + ",ssh-rsa")
JSch.setConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", JSch.getConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms") + ",ssh-rsa")
val jsch = new JSch()
jsch.addIdentity(relPathPrivateKey)
val session = jsch.getSession(usernameAtRemote, remoteIp, 22)
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
session.connect()   // session is verified connected & authenticated after this call
val assignedPort: Int = session.setPortForwardingL(tunnelLocalPort, localhost, remotePort)
val socket = new Socket(localhost, assignedPort)
val inputStream = socket.getInputStream
val outputStream = socket.getOutputStream
val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
val writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream)
writer.println(auth)
readLines(bufferedReader)
socket.close()
session.disconnect()

// com.jcraft.jsch.Channel
protected void sendChannelOpen() throws Exception {
  // ... lines 819-821 below ...
  if (this.open_confirmation == false) { // SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_OPEN_FAILURE
    throw new JSchException("channel is not opened.");  // <== FAILS HERE in DirectTCPIP thread
  }
  // ...
}
```

When I try **session.getStreamForwarder** and I try `channel.connect()`, it throws `JSchException("session is down")` at the end of `sendChannelOpen` in `Channel.java` in the main thread.

```
JSch.setConfig("server_host_key", JSch.getConfig("server_host_key") + ",ssh-rsa")
JSch.setConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", JSch.getConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms") + ",ssh-rsa")
val jsch = new JSch()
jsch.addIdentity(relPathPrivateKey)
val session = jsch.getSession(usernameAtRemote, remoteIp, 22)
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no")
session.connect()   // session is verified connected & authenticated after this call
val channel = session.getStreamForwarder(remoteIp, remotePort)
channel.connect()   // this FAILS
val inputStream = channel.getInputStream
val outputStream = channel.getOutputStream
val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
val writer = new PrintWriter(outputStream)
writer.println(auth)
readLines(bufferedReader)
channel.disconnect()
session.disconnect()

// com.jcraft.jsch.Channel
protected void sendChannelOpen() throws Exception {
  // ... lines 816-818 below ...
  if (!_session.isConnected()) {
    throw new JSchException("session is down");  // <== FAILS HERE in main thread
  }
  // ...
}
```

**Code below is from original post, here for original discussion context only, and can be ignored for now. Instead see the code segments inserted above, as a commenter requested I show new code.**

Here is some test code in Scala calling JSch. I realize it's rough. I'm just trying to get JSch to work for me.

```
import com.jcraft.jsch._

object Main extends Log4JLogging {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // $ ssh -l username -L LOCALPORT:127.0.0.1:REMOTEPORT REMOTEHOST
    // $ ID='{ "id": 1234, "auth": "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" }'
    // $ while true; do echo $ID; sleep 10; done | nc localhost LOCALPORT

    val remoteIpaddr = "123.45.54.321"
    val localhost = "127.0.0.1"
    val sshPort = 22
    val tunnelLocalPort = LOCALPORT
    val tunnelRemotePort = REMOTEPORT

    val usernameAtRemoteHost = "username"
    val privateKeyForRemoteHost = "ssh/for-remotehost/id_rsa"

    val auth = "{ \"id\": 1234, \"auth\": \"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\" }\n"
    try {
      val currentWorkingDirectory: String = System.getProperty("user.dir")
      val pathPrivateKeyForRemoteHost: String = s"$currentWorkingDirectory/$privateKeyForRemoteHost"
      JSch.setConfig("server_host_key", JSch.getConfig("server_host_key") + ",ssh-rsa")
      JSch.setConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms", JSch.getConfig("PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms") + ",ssh-rsa")
      val tunnelJSch = new JSch()
      tunnelJSch.addIdentity(pathPrivateKeyForRemoteHost)
      val tunnelSessionPort = sshPort
      val tunnelSession = tunnelJSch.getSession(usernameAtRemoteHost, remoteIpaddr, tunnelSessionPort)
      tunnelSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no") // yes I know this is bad, will change once things work
      tunnelSession.setPortForwardingL(tunnelLocalPort, localhost, tunnelRemotePort)
      tunnelSession.connect()

      val tunnelChannel = tunnelSession.openChannel("direct-tcpip")
      val input = tunnelChannel.getInputStream()
      val output = tunnelChannel.getOutputStream()
      tunnelChannel.connect()
//      tunnelChannel.setInputStream(System.in)
//      tunnelChannel.setOutputStream(System.out)
      output.write(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
      val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
      var n = input.read(buffer)
      while (n > 0) {
        n = input.read(buffer)
      }
//      val dataJsch = new JSch()
//      dataJsch.addIdentity(pathPrivateKeyForRemoteHost)
//      val dataSession = dataJsch.getSession(usernameAtRemoteHost, localhost, tunnelLocalPort)
//      dataSession.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no") // yes I know this is bad, will change once things work
//
//      val dataChannel = dataSession.openChannel("forwarded-tcpip")
//      dataChannel.setInputStream(System.in)
//      dataChannel.setOutputStream(System.out)
//      dataChannel.connect()
//
//      val input = dataChannel.getInputStream()
//      val output = dataChannel.getOutputStream()
//      output.write(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
//      val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)
//      var n = input.read(buffer)
//      while (n > 0) {
//        n = input.read(buffer)
//      }
//      dataChannel.disconnect()
      tunnelSession.disconnect()
    } catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        logStackTrace(e)
    System.exit(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you expect the `direct-tcpip` to be somehow magically connected to the `setPortForwardingL`. I'm quite sure it won't. You are basically trying twice the same thing, but in neither case you do all that is needed.

Either:

- Use `Session.setPortForwardingL` to forward a local port and connect `Socket` to `localhost:tunnelLocalPort` and talk to the remote side over it. That's an overkill, but maybe easier to implement.
- Or correctly setup the `tunnelChannel` (by calling `setHost` and `setPort`). Or rather use `Session.getStreamForwarder` that does exactly that. And talk to the remote side directly over the channel, without need for a physical local port. The local port is only needed as an interface to another process. If you have everything within one process, you do not need the port. It would be just an additional useless layer.